# How to check the "msg.value" on another currencies

Tags: solidity, erc-721, nft, mint

I'm doing an ERC721 smart contract for an NFT project. They are going to use the Polygon network, and as far as I know, ETH smart contracts work fine on them. But there is a problem, they want the mint price to be 25 MATIC, and the smart contract that I did uses the price in ETH, how can I do a smart contract that requires 25 MATIC?
Here is the piece of code for the mint function:

```
  function mint(uint256 count) public payable nonReentrant {
    require(saleIsActive, "Sale not active");

    if (allowedMintCount(_msgSender()) >= count) {
      updateMintCount(_msgSender(), count);
    } else {
      revert("Minting limit exceeded");
    }

    require(totalSupply() + count - 1 < MAX_SUPPLY, "Exceeds max supply");

    require(count <= MAX_MULTIMINT, "Mint at most 20 at a time");

    require(
      msg.value >= PRICE * count, "Insufficient payment, 25 MATIC per item"
    );

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      _safeMint(_msgSender(), totalSupply());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Matic, BNB, and others are handled like ether on their own blockchain. Therefore solidity don't care about it and msg.value return the amount of the transferred native token. 
but you need to test it to understand it